# Can we replace outliers with the predicted values in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql, outliers

I have a df in spark:
(I am actually working on this dataset it is not possible to paste whole data so here is the link)

df = https://www.kaggle.com/schirmerchad/bostonhoustingmlnd?select=housing.csv

Now I found the outliers as below (22 rows in total):

```
    def IQR(df,column):
         quantiles = sdf.approxQuantile(column, [0.25, 0.75], 0)
         q1 = quantiles[0]
         q3 = quantiles[1]
         IQR = q3-q1
         lower = q1 - 1.5*IQR
         upper = q3+ 1.5*IQR
     return (lower,upper)
   lower, upper = IQR(df,'RM')
   lower,upper = 4.8374999999999995 7.617500000000001
   outliers = df.filter((df['RM'] > upper) | (df['RM'] < lower))
```

Now below are the outliers detected :

```
RM  LSTAT   PTRATIO MEDV
8.069   4.21    18  812700
7.82    3.57    18  919800
7.765   7.56    17.8    835800
7.853   3.81    14.7    1018500
8.266   4.14    17.4    940800
8.04    3.13    17.4    789600
7.686   3.92    17.4    980700
8.337   2.47    17.4    875700
8.247   3.95    17.4    1014300
8.259   3.54    19.1    898800
8.398   5.91    13  1024800
7.691   6.58    18.6    739200
7.82    3.76    14.9    953400
7.645   3.01    14.9    966000
3.561   7.12    20.2    577500
3.863   13.33   20.2    485100
4.138   37.97   20.2    289800
4.368   30.63   20.2    184800
4.652   28.28   20.2    220500
4.138   23.34   20.2    249900
4.628   34.37   20.2    375900
4.519   36.98   20.2    147000
```

Now I want to replace the outliers with the ml predicted values, after the ml process I got the predicted values as below:-

```
  RM    LSTAT   PTRATIO MEDV    column_assem        column          prediction
8.069   4.21    18  812700  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[4.21,18,812700]} {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[812699.9991344779,32.9872628621034,25.697942748362507]}  7.138307692307692
7.82    3.57    18  919800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.57,18,919800]} {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[919799.999082192,36.25675952004636,26.656936598060938]}  7.138307692307692
7.765   7.56    17.8    835800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[7.56,17.8,835800]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[835799.9989959698,37.18609141885786,25.87518521779868]}  7.138307692307692
7.853   3.81    14.7    1018500 {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.81,14.7,1018500]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[1018499.9990279829,40.25963007114179,24.285126110831364]}    7.138307692307692
8.266   4.14    17.4    940800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[4.14,17.4,940800]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[940799.9990507461,37.621770135316275,26.279618209844216]}    7.138307692307692
8.04    3.13    17.4    789600  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.13,17.4,789600]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[789599.999195178,31.094759131505864,24.832393813608636]} 7.138307692307692
7.686   3.92    17.4    980700  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.92,17.4,980700]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[980699.9990305867,38.858227336579965,26.637789595102927]}    7.138307692307692
8.337   2.47    17.4    875700  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[2.47,17.4,875700]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[875699.9991585133,33.577861049146954,25.59625197564997]} 7.138307692307692
8.247   3.95    17.4    1014300 {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.95,17.4,1014300]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[1014299.9990056665,40.11446130241714,26.949909126197]}   7.138307692307692
8.259   3.54    19.1    898800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.54,19.1,898800]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[898799.9990899825,35.406713649671325,27.56000332051734]} 7.138307692307692
8.398   5.91    13  1024800 {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[5.91,13,1024800]}    {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[1024799.9989586923,42.669988999612016,22.74784587477886]}    7.138307692307692
7.691   6.58    18.6    739200  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[6.58,18.6,739200]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[739199.9990946348,32.64270527156902,25.73328780757773]}  7.138307692307692
7.82    3.76    14.9    953400  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.76,14.9,953400]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[953399.9990744753,37.82403517229104,23.880552758747136]} 7.138307692307692
7.645   3.01    14.9    966000  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[3.01,14.9,966000]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[965999.9990932231,37.53477931241747,23.960460322415766]} 7.138307692307692
3.561   7.12    20.2    577500  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[7.12,20.2,577500]}   {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[577499.9991773808,27.20258411502299,25.862694427868608]} 6.376732394366198
3.863   13.33   20.2    485100  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[13.33,20.2,485100]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[485099.999013695,30.032948373359417,25.311342678468208]} 6.043858108108108
4.138   37.97   20.2    289800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[37.97,20.2,289800]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[289799.99824280146,47.51591753902686,24.707706732637366]}    5.2370714285714275
4.368   30.63   20.2    184800  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[30.63,20.2,184800]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[184799.99858809082,36.35256433967503,23.378827944979733]}    5.2370714285714275
4.652   28.28   20.2    220500  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[28.28,20.2,220500]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[220499.9986495131,35.3082739723793,23.59425617851294]}   5.2370714285714275
4.138   23.34   20.2    249900  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[23.34,20.2,249900]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[249899.99881098093,31.44714189260281,23.625084354536643]}    6.043858108108108
4.628   34.37   20.2    375900  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[34.37,20.2,375900]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[375899.9983146336,47.06252004732307,25.328138233469573]} 5.2370714285714275
4.519   36.98   20.2    147000  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[36.98,20.2,147000]}  {"vectorType":"dense","length":3,"values":[146999.99838054206,41.31545014321207,23.33912202640834]} 5.2370714285714275
```

If it is one value I am aware of `lit()` to replace it but when there are multiple values how do we replace with the original one's?

Comment: how do you know which value corresponds to which brand?

Comment: @mck the values are predicted sequentially right? like one after the other?

Comment: is there other columns in test_df?

Comment: @mck Yes, all other columns along with the converted vector assembler, standard scaler and etc.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show the label column, which I guess is the brand? Otherwise I couldn't know which prediction corresponds to which brand...

Comment: @mck I am sorry, I felt that before posting. I am dealing with the dataset which I posted now could you please re-check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the original dataframe is called `df` and the machine-learning transformed dataframe is called `ml`, you can do a join and replace the RM column with the prediction value if the row satisfy the outlier condition:

```
df2 = df.join(ml, df.columns, 'left').withColumn(
    'RM', 
    F.when(
        (F.col('RM') > upper) | (F.col('RM') < lower), 
        F.col('prediction')
    ).otherwise(F.col('RM'))
).select(df.columns)
```